# tiling two images in background in ie8

Tags: html, css, background-image, tiling

I have a 10px x 765px graphic that I repeat-x, then I have a repeating graphic that is 20px x 20px that I want to pick up once the page goes beyond 765px in height.

Is it possible to do this?

```
body {
  background: #000 url('/assets/images/background_x_tile.png') repeat-x;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Both background images included here, I don't know how to tile the smaller image once the page reaches the end of the 765px height image.

Trying to accomplish what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: it's working fine by using "body {
  background:url(image_url) repeat-x;
}"

Comment: Try to use media query for this.."@media screen and (min-width: 765px) and (orientation: landscape)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one bg image on the `html` tag and another on the `body` tag

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/CIsdj)

```
html {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yowiu.png);
   background-position: 765px 0;
}

body {
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtvK0.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the 20px x 20px image as a background image to the HTML element and have the 10px x 765px image as a background to the body element.

If this solution doesn't meet your needs you could look at adding a CSS media block like:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 765px)
```

More information on CSS @media blocks here:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score -1):

```
background-size:cover
```

this will not give the effect you are desiring for. simply add the above code to the `css` where you have applied background.

Almost gives the same output :)